# Fetch Data From Database with Php and Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hi i'm not sure what i'm doing worning :D
I'm working with php and js to fetch data from my db and make a user view table.
I guess i need to put all my echos in a variable or some thing like that. But i'm not sure. Thanks every one for the support.

my js fucntion

```js
function dataT(){
    $.ajax({
      type:'Post',
      url:'filltable.php',
      data:{context :' showusers'},
      success:function (data){
        $('#content').html(data);
      }
    });

    alert(data);
  }
```

my html code

```html
  <body onload="dataT()">
  
    <div class="row">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h3>tabla</h3>
        <br>
        <table id="dt" class="table table-hover ">
          <thead>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>UN</th>
            <th>Mail</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
          </thead>
          <tbody id="content">

          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3"></div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Here is where i'm fetching with php

```js
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

  try {
       $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=kyo", $username, $password);
       // set the PDO error mode to exception
       $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


       if($_POST['context']=='showusers'){
         fillT($conn);
       }

       //end try
       }
    catch(PDOException $e)
       {
       echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
       }



       function fillT(){
         $sql = "SELECT `username`, `mail`, id FROM `users` ";
         $res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

         if(!$res){
           die("Error!!! ... D:");
         }else{
           while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res) ) {
             ?>
             <tr>
               <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
               <td><?php echo $row['username']; ?></td>
               <td><?php echo $row['mail']; ?></td>
             </tr>
             <?php
           }
           echo json_encode($data);
         }

         mysqli_free_result($res);
         mysqli_close($conn);
       }
?>
```

Comment: are you getting data in PHP?

Comment: how you are calling php function?

Comment: Your php code has log of mistakes. Check server logs for more information

Comment: display errors error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: Yes it's getting, called by onload

Comment: According to your code, you need to return html instead of ```$data```. Store the generated html in any variable and then echo it.

Comment: @EduardoRawrdríguez but in js its ' showusers' and in php its 'showusers' are you sure your php function is called?

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
  <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";

  try {
       $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=kyo", $username, $password);
       // set the PDO error mode to exception
       $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

       //end try
       }
    catch(PDOException $e)
       {
       echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
       }
?>

<body>

    <div class="row">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h3>tabla</h3>
        <br>
        <table id="dt" class="table table-hover ">
          <thead>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>UN</th>
            <th>Mail</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
          </thead>
          <tbody id="content">


  <?php
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT `username`, `mail`, id FROM `users` "); 
    $stmt->execute();

// set the resulting array to associative
$result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
          foreach($stmt->fetchAll() as $row){
             ?>
             <tr>
               <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
               <td><?php echo $row['username']; ?></td>
               <td><?php echo $row['mail']; ?></td>
               <td><?php echo "actions"; ?></td>
             </tr>
             <?php
         }
?>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3"></div>

    </div>
  </div>
```